# ROOM, SQLite and class hierarchy

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-room, class-hierarchy

So, this is my problem. I've been googling for some time now and no other question on this topic seems to approach what bugs me.

In my Android application, I have a class hierarchy, a list of tourist attractions. Every TouristAttraction has, among others, a boolean attribute that specifies whether that attraction is among user's "favorite" attractions.

However, when I insert a specific type of a tourist attraction, say a Monument, Room insert puts both inherited and specific attributes in one table and not in superclass table, so when I want to get a list of all "favorite" attractions, I have to combine results of select queries for every subclass.

Also, when I want to mark something as favorite, this way I first have to see what type of tourist attraction it is, and then get specific DAO... which seems kinda ugly. Is there a way to, when I insert a new row in Monument table, data from inherited fields gets inserted into superclass table?

This problem happens every time I need to collect data that every tourist attraction has, like location etc.

Answer (score 0):

Im not familiar with android-room. But from a sqlite point of view I would structure your TouristAttactions in a separate table without any favorite flags. And then have a second table with the mapping between the user's favorite and attractions.

```
CREATE TABLE tabTouristAttrations (ID INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT, Name TEXT, ...);
CREATE TABLE mapFavoritesUser (AttrID INTEGER NOT NULL, UserID INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (AttrID, UserID)
```

cheers
Andy